# How to write two consecutive lines from file in python?

Tags: python, file-handling

```
old = open('./old.txt')
new = open('./new.txt','w')
for line in file:
    if '22%' in line:
        new.write(line)
new.close()
```

the above code writes lines containing 22% into a new file. what changes should be made to also write the line that comes immediately after the line containing 22%?

example:
old.txt has

```
abc

def

g22%hi

jkl

mno
```

new.txt should have

```
g22%hi

jkl
```

Comment: Something like: `new.write(next(file, ''))` inside your if should work.

Comment: This is not your real code. It will throw an error because ``file`` is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a flag or use `next` as others said in comments:

```
some_flag = False
for line in file:
    if some_flag:
        new.write(line)
        some_flag = False
    if '22%' in line:
        new.write(line)
        some_flag = True

new.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest change you can do to your existing code, and solve the question is:

```
old = open('./old.txt')
new = open('./new.txt','w')
prevLine = ""
for line in file:
    if '22%' in line or '22%' in prevLine:
        prevLine = line
        new.write(line)
new.close()
```